# Problem with code Error BC30311 array list double

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, double, combinations

I am having the following problem, at line 32. OutpuList.Add(tempList)
Error BC30311: system.collections.generic.list(of double) can not be converted to 1-d matrix of double.
Does anybody have a fix for this or knows on how to put the result in a datatable, this would be even better. Have been struggling with the code for ages.

The code gets every possible combination of an array of doubles and put it back into a list of double[].
I have a target value which i want check with each sum of each combination.

```
Dim n As Int32
Dim i As Int32
Dim j As Int32
Dim counter As Int32
Dim binary As Int32
Dim skipCount As Int32
n = CInt(InputArray.Length)
Dim tempArr(n,CInt(Math.Pow(CDbl(2),CDbl(n)))) as Int32
Dim tempList As New List(Of Double)
OutpuList = New List(of Double())
skipCount = CInt(Math.Pow(CDbl(2),CDbl(n)))
For j=0 To n-1
 skipcount=CInt(skipCount/2)
 binary = 1
 counter = 0
 For i=0 To CInt(Math.Pow(CDbl(2),CDbl(n)))-1
  temparr(j,i)=binary
  counter=(counter + 1) Mod skipCount
  If counter = 0 Then
   binary = (binary + 1) Mod 2
  End If
 Next i
Next j

For i=0 To CInt(Math.Pow(CDbl(2),CDbl(n)))-1
 tempList = New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of double)
 For j=0 To n-1
  If tempArr(j,i)=1 Then
  templist.Add(InputArray(j))
  End If
 Next j
 OutpuList.Add(tempList)
Next i
```

Comment: `OutpuList.Add(tempList.ToArray())` (unrelated: your `OutpuList` is missing a `t` :)

Comment: Absolute Hero, Any clue on how to set it to a datatable after?

Comment: No questions in comments. Ask another question.